# node request module server crashes when piping invalid url

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, node-request

I've been struggling with this for 2 days :/ I'm using express request to upload external files to server...

```
var dest = "downloads/imgs";
var filename = "image";
var url = "http://pngimg.com/uploads/spongebob/spongebob_PNG27.png"

var file = fs.createWriteStream(dest + "/" + filename +     path.extname(url));

request.get(url)
.on('error', function(err) {
    console.log(err);
    return;
}).pipe(file);

file.on('error', function(err) {
    file.end();
});
file.on('finish', function() {
    file.close();
});
```

This works fine. Except if I insert a wrong url, I get an invalid URI error and the server crashes, instead of catching the error. Any idea why on.error return is not working?

Answer (score 1):

I think what's happing is the code is trying to pipe notwithstanding the error condition on the http request.  Only do the file i/o on a good download...

```
var dest = "downloads/imgs";
var filename = "image";
var url = "http://pngimg.com/uploads/spongebob/spongebob_PNG27.png"

let fn = dest + "/" + filename +     path.extname(url);
var file = fs.createWriteStream(fn);

request
  .get(url)
  .on('error', function(err) {
    console.log('caught error ' + err);
    return;
  })  // instead of piping here...
  .on('response', function(response) {
    response.pipe(file);
    console.log(`wrote to ` + fn);
  })

file.on('error', function(err) {
    file.end();
});

file.on('finish', function() {
    file.close();
});
```